# Que veut dire « J'ai pris mes larmes à mon cou » ici ?

Tags: locutions, paroles-de-chanson, jeux-de-mots

Je me demande si j’ai compris cette partie de la chanson « on se ressemble » des Vieilles Valises. Pouvez-vous me dire si mes pensées vous paraissent justes ?

> J'ai pris mes larmes à mon cou
>   J'me suis enfui sans dire un mot
>   En direction de n'importe où
>   Noyer mon cœur dans un bistrot !

Ma question n’a trait qu’à la première phrase que j’ai ajoutée ci-dessous. J’ai résolu d’inclure les autres phrases pour le cas où cela apporte de la clarté.

La première ligne m’étonne. Elle semble avoir de la convenance avec la locution « prendre ses jambes à son cou », hormis que l’on a remplacé le mot *jambes* par *larmes*. 
Quand je lis la locution comme je la connais, je pense à quelqu’un qui court en bougeant ses jambes si vivement qu’elles atteignent son cou à chaque pas. Quand je vois ce morceau de la chanson, je ne sais pas vraiment qu’est-ce qui je dois me représenter dans l’esprit.

Je pense que le parolier ainsi exprime que le personnage s’en va parce qu’il est rempli de tristesse, alors que la locution sans changement laisse penser que quelqu’un est épouvanté de quelque chose et s’enfuit pour se sauver.

Comment: Ça doit faire dix fois qu’une tentative d’encastrer un cadre jaune échoue. Je me suis enfin contenté de faire un cadre gris, car les lignes se joignent quand j’essaie d’afficher les paroles dans un champ jaune. Un indice pour contourner cet encombrement est le bienvenu !

Comment: Mets un `>` au début, et pense à ajouter deux espaces chaque fois que tu veux indiquer un saut de ligne.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Il s'agit d'un jeu de mots avec l'expression "prendre ses jambes à son cou" qui veut dire s'enfuir rapidement. Ici, le remplacement de "jambes" par "larmes" implique que la personne s'est enfuie rapidement à cause de sa tristesse, ce que les autres vers confirment en ajoutant que la personne s'est "enfui[e] sans dire un mot" pour "noyer [s]on coeur dans un bistrot".